# Why is my conditional validation failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

I have a conditional validation in my Post model:

```
validates :title, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new { |post| post.post_type == "text" }
```

And I have the following spec in my `post_spec.rb` file:

```
it "should only require a title if the post type is text" do
  post = Post.new(@attr.merge(:title => "", :post_type => "text"))
  post.should_not be_valid

  post = Post.new(@attr.merge(:title => "", :post_type => "image"))
  post.should be_valid # This fails
end
```

My question is: **Why does the second test fail?**

Comment: Should we assume there are no other validations that can fail, and the remaining values in `@attr` are valid?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the empty title from the second post creation the validation passes. So it's the title validation that fails, the others are valid.

Comment: If you changed the rule to something like `post.errors.should be_empty` you'll at least get a more descriptive fail.  (or even `post.errors[:title]`, since that's what you're testing)'

Comment: @numbers1311407: That's the weird part, if I do what you said, the test passes but the post is not valid, there just aren't any error messages, which is really weird...

Comment: Anything else in your model, like `attr_accessible`/`attr_protected`?

Comment: That's my whole model as of now. I modified the condition a bit, but it's equivalent, and I still have a failing test (two actually, one similar one for the body): https://gist.github.com/9e993d66a34a1f576900

Comment: I've seen many questions on so these days reporting weird behaviors with the 'be_valid' matcher

Comment: I tested my app thoroughly and I am positive that the condition is always true and the title validation is always enabled. It's not an RSpec issue.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix the problem. For constructive purposes, here is my lates model: http://scrp.at/aoL

Comment: You could probably try splitting your test like in the example [here](http://snipplr.com/view/49991/shoulda-with-testunit-conditional-validation-using-shouldasubject/).  It seems to be something wrong with the test and not the model code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some other validation somewhere failing.  Go into your rails console and do:

```
post = Post.new(:title => "", :post_type => "image")
post.valid?
post.errors
```

and see what you get...